# Google Spreadsheet Script: Is a sheet hidden or visible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a custom Google Spreadsheet function, is there any way to determine if a `sheet` (tab) is hidden or visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has recently added the ability to [hide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideSheet%28%29) and [show](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showSheet%28%29) sheets. To know whether the sheet is hidden, a new function [isSheetHidden()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isSheetHidden%28%29) has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley Hide/Unhide classes for spreadsheets are unsupported. There is an [open enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=995&q=hide%20sheet&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner).  For hiding/showing sheets; you might like to star /comment it to be kept updated.

Comment: Yup I know about that. I had already starred it few weeks back. I was wondering if there was a clever way just to determine if a particular sheet was hidden or visible.

Comment: you mean some sort of work around?  let me think about that, ill repost, if I can think of anything.