# Google Apps Scripts in the Button to show/hide sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create one button to show/hide sheet

```
function hideSheet() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Calculation").hideSheet();
}
hideSheet("Calculation");
```

However, I don't know how to insert if statement. If it is not hidden, hide it. If it's hidden, unhide it.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593097/google-spreadsheet-script-is-a-sheet-hidden-or-visible

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for this which you can [find here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0L2K7AXufw&t=897s). And you can find the reference here:

[- isSheetHidden](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#issheethidden)

[- showSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showSheet())

[- hideSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet)

```js
  function showSheet(){
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Hidden Sheet");
    if( sheet.isSheetHidden() ) sheet.showSheet()
  }
  
  function hideSheet(){
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Hidden Sheet");
    if( !sheet.isSheetHidden() ) sheet.hideSheet()
  }
```

Comment: It is working! The link you provided is very useful.

Comment: Glad I could help, then please mark my answer is checked so that this case is closed.