# VBA Macro to Google Apps Script Macro: To Visible Sheets Only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm moving my Excel workbook into Google Sheets and I'm so far able to recreate a good hunk of my codes in Apps Script but I ran into an issue. It's the Macro to change a sheet if it is visible other wise move on the the next sheet that is visible. It's an IF THEN ELSE IF when I made it on VBA, Is there a way to do the same in Apps Script?

The Original VBA code I want to make for Google Apps Script:

```
    If Sheets("Apples").Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
         Sheets("Apples").Select
         Range("C29").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Red"
 
     ElseIf Sheets("Pears").Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
         Sheets("Pears").Select
         Range("C17").Select
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Green"
    End If
    Sheets("Fruit").Select
```

Comment: Hi. Have you read StackOverflow: [Google Apps Scripts in the Button to show/hide sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263920/1330560)?

Comment: @Tedinoz That function is not what I'm trying to do. The macro I'm making releases the next set of data and if a sheet is visible before the macro runs, it adds data, if not visible then either move on to the next visible sheet or end script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue: Instead of looking for a visible sheet I just did an IF this cell === 'name' then go to this sheet make changes. but what is hidden stays hidden unless make visible by the user. it is true it still make changes to the hidden sheet but it still stay hidden, I'm fine with that cause there is a reset macro to correct it all. I'm sure it doesn't make sense but it did what I needed it to do. If you think there is a cleaner or better way to do do this I'm all ears, But thank you all for the help.

```
  if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell() === 'Apples');{
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Apple Color'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('C29').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Red')
    }
  if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell() === 'Pears');{
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Pear Color'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('C29').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Green')
    }
```

Comment: May I ask... 1) `getCurrentCell()` - there are at least 3 possible contexts for `getCurrentCell()`: "SpreadsheetApp", "Sheet", & "Selection". How have you set the variable "spreadsheet"?  2) What do you understand is happening in `if (spreadsheet.getCurrentCell() === 'Apples')`? My testing shows that **both** `if` statements return as true regardless of the location of the current cell.